# Retrieving a Has Many Model Values with django-rest-framework serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='address')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can i retrieve the address of a specific user using drf serializers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1: Write Serializer for both User Model and Address Model.
serializers.py

```
UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for User Model"""
   address = AddressSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_fields = ["address"]

AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for Address Model"""

    class Meta:
        model = Adddress
        fields = "__all__"
```

Step 2: Write Query for your User Model for serialize your data.

views.py:

```
 queryset = User.objects.all().prefetch_related("address")
 serializer = UserSerializer(data=queryset)
 print(serializer.data)  # you will get all your user with their addresses.
```

Comment: Thanks you very much @MSI Shafik. Your answer was really great full!